# How to know if information between 2 servers is secured (SSL)?

Tags: web-services, apache, security, ssl

We have 2 servers SerA and SerB. SerA has apache2 and SSL with a SSL certificate, and SerB has has a Web Service that only lets connections from SerA.

We need to connect the client with SerB through SerA, and the approach used is doing it with a proxy, but we need to know if the connection between the Client and SerB, and SerA and SerB are secured. How could we know that?

Comment: @user2246674 As stated there is no reason given to believe that SerA<->SerB actually uses SSL just because it is present. You would have to sniff the network, or check the application in B.

Comment: The connection between SerA and Serb doesnt have SSL, only between the client and SerA.

Comment: We dont know, that is the problem :-) 

The thing is:

`Client <---SSL---> SerA <--"we dont know", "Web Logic" -->SerB`

`Client <-- ??? --> SerB`

Comment: @user2246674 You keep making unwarranted assumptions. There's no evidence that the certificates are unused. The A/B path could use HTTPS or SSL for some communications and not for others.

Comment: @EJP Is it "too obvious" that an unsecured connection is unsecured? Clearly my statements were made on the *assumption* that this basic premise was understood. I have no further input.

Comment: In theory, there's no difference between the theory and practice. In practice, there is. Maybe "the SSL is on", but , how could we know it for sure? The work is for a bank transaction, and we need to be 100% sure that the connection is secured, not only by saying "yeah! it says https instead of http"

Comment: @user2246674 I have no idea what your latest comment is supposed to mean, and as all your other comments have been deleted, there is now no evidence at all about what your other statements even were, let alone anything being clear about their underlying assumptions. Let me restate. The presence of an SSL certificate is a necessary but not sufficient condition for connection security. If it wasn't there you could validly conclude there was no security, but the converse deduction isn't valid.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. To what extent are the networks between `A` and `B` trusted? Do `A` and `B` talk over the internet? Are they in the same data center? Can the proxy on `A` be configured to only talk SSL to server `B`? Is that even necessary if they are in the same data center? (most proxy configurations I've seen terminate SSL and then run plain HTTP connections to back-end web services)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from your post what scripting language you are using on SerA and SerB to drive this application.  But, most scripting languages give you access to an environment variable that you can use to determine whether the client's connection to the server is by way of HTTPS or HTTP.  For example, in PHP, the environment variable is: `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`